# Zend Framework App with static html pointed to domain root

Tags: php, zend-framework, directoryindex

A Zend newbie here. Please help.

We've deployed a bunch of static html pages (in `var/www/html`) and then a ZF app to our server. We want `www.ourdomain.com` to point to the `index.html` (static html) and not redirect to our ZF app (`index.php`). Only when we explicitly call `www.ourdomain.com/login` should the ZF app be invoked. Right now, `www.ourdomain.com` just redirects to our ZF app !.

Can you please advise !.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure apache to use index.html as directory index:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

(You can add this in a .htaccess in /var/www/html)